# vdo: ERROR - Device /dev/sdc excluded by a filter

Tags: redhat, lvm, rhel8, vdo

After creating a third disk in vagrant/virtualbox, I was getting this error while trying to create a VDO (Red Hat's Enterprise Linux 8 tool for deduplication and compression).

For LVM you usually go like this:

```
parted -s /dev/sdc mklabel gpt
parted -s /dev/sdc mkpart xfs 2048s 2G
```

So, I did the first step, declaring the partition table type to GPT for VDO:

```
parted -s /dev/sdc mklabel gpt
```

And omitted the partition, as this wasn't needed.

The drive looked like:

```
$ fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 5 GiB, 5368709120 bytes, 10485760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3ACED1E3-DB5A-4240-99C3-AD280212XXXX
```

After this, trying to create the VDO volume ended in error:

```
vdo create --name=vdo1 --device=/dev/sdc --vdoLogicalSize=10T
Creating VDO vdo1
vdo: ERROR - Device /dev/sdc excluded by a filter.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was similar to those found in related LVM posts regarding the label of the disk. It seems that VDO doesn't need (and support) to have the disk labelled as gpt, so we have to wipe it:

```
# wipefs -a /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000200 (gpt): 45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54
/dev/sdc: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x13ffffe00 (gpt): 45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54
/dev/sdc: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (PMBR): 55 aa
/dev/sdc: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
```

This will leave the disk without label:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 5 GiB, 5368709120 bytes, 10485760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

And VDO will create the volume:

```
# vdo create --name=vdo1 --device=/dev/sdc --vdoLogicalSize=10T
Creating VDO vdo1
Starting VDO vdo1
Starting compression on VDO vdo1
VDO instance 0 volume is ready at /dev/mapper/vdo1
```